# Python3, Flask. Постоянно перенаправляет запрос

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redirect

Использовал код, в котором применялось перенаправление:

```
@app.route('/', redirect_to='/hello')
def index():
    return #########
```

Файл удален, но теперь при каждом запуске Flask при переходе на страницу по умолчанию 127.0.0.1 происхожит перенаправление на 127.0.0.1/hello

Comment: Атрибут `redirect_to='/hello'` ведь перенаправляет запрос к `app.route('/hello'`. Непонятно про какой файл вы говорите

Comment: Может вы не там файл удалили, а запущен он совсем в другом месте? )

Comment: Речь идет о файле, в котором и был указанный выше код. Файл удален. Но при попытке FLASK_APP по прежнему ссылается на этот файл. Попытка сменить значение не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что проблема в браузере, в котором вы тестируете свой продукт. **Попробуйте почистить кэш или, как вариант, использовать другой браузер**. Дайте знать, помогло или нет.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/670092)

Comment: почистить кэш и/или использовать другой браузер - моё предлагаемое решение. Просьба внимательно читать текст.